# Finding two newest files in two separate directories and merging them

Tags: perl

I have two direcotries, each containing pictures. The regional directory is updated every 5 minutes, the watch directory is updated every 15.

What I am trying to do is find the newest file in each directory and take those files and use *Image Magik* to create a third image.

What I have works for some but is very inconsistent, for example my code will sometimes miss the regional files when it's time matches the watch files.

Other times it will merge two watch files, even though the watch files and regional files are in two separate directories.

I have no clue how to fix it.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

use vars qw/%files_watch/;
use vars qw/%files_regional/;

sub findNewestFiles {
    my $element = $File::Find::name;
    return if ( !-f $element );

    $files_watch{$element} = ( stat($element) )[10];
    $files_regional{$element} = ( stat($element) )[10];

}

my $image_magick_exe = "composite.exe\"";
my $pic_dir = "C:\\eterra\\eterravision\\weather";
my $watch_dir = "C:\\eterra\\eterravision\\weather\\watch";
my $regional_dir = "C:\\eterra\\eterravision\\weather\\regional";

open( OUT, ">>names.txt" ) || die;

find( \&findNewestFiles, $watch_dir );
my $newestfile_watch;
my $time_watch = 0;

while ( my ( $t1, $t2 ) = each(%files_watch) ) {
    if ( $t2 > $time_watch ) {
        $newestfile_watch = $t1;
        $time_watch       = $t2;

    }

}

$time_watch = localtime($time_watch);

find( \&findNewestFiles, $regional_dir );
my $newestfile_regional;
my $time_regional = 0;

while ( my ( $t3, $t4 ) = each(%files_regional) ) {
    if ( $t4 > $time_regional ) {
        $newestfile_regional = $t3;
        $time_regional       = $t4;

    }
}

$time_regional = localtime($time_regional);

$newestfile_watch =~ s/\//\\/g;
$newestfile_regional =~ s/\//\\/g;    #replacing the "/" in the file path to "\"

my @temp = split( /_/, $newestfile_regional );

my $type = $temp[0];
my $date = $temp[1];
my $time = $temp[2];

my $check = "$pic_dir/radarwatch\_$date\_$time";    #check if file was created

unless ( -e $check )

{

    system("\"$image_magick_exe \"$newestfile_regional\" \"$newestfile_watch\"      \"$pic_dir\\radarwatch\_$date\_$time\"");

    print "file created\n";
}
```

I changed the [10] in the sub function to an [8], and a [9]. 8 is access time, 9 is modification time, and 10 is creation time, 10 hase been the most successful.

I think the problem is with the sub function.
Is there a better way to search for the newest creation time? Something that is more reliable than what I have?

Comment: You can write `my ($type, $date, $time) = split( /_/, $newestfile_regional );` to avoid the `@temp`. You open an `OUT` handle but you are not using it. It is in general a good idea to break down the problem to a minimal example. As it stands it is not a real question but fix-my-code request what is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: thank you anyway, i applogize for the miss use of the site.

Comment: Do not be too defensive. Just try to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11650725/edit) your post according to the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) :)

Comment: this is my first time posting here, so i was not familiar with the rules here, i did edit and asked a direct question. i think this should be good

Comment: In sub findNewestFiles, you stat the same file twice.  Perhaps you meant to stat the file once in each directory?  mtime should work best for your application.  The name "findNewestFiles" is misleading, it is finding and storing the time of each file in the watch directory, twice.  The English is a little confusing of what you are trying to do.  Is one new file dumped into each directory every few minutes?  And you are trying to find the single newest file in each directory to process?

Answer (score 0):

I think the crux of your problem is finding the most recent file in each directory, and then processing them.  Leaving aside the details of processing them, here is a script that finds the most recent files.  I leave out the imagemagick stuff, that can all be put into the process_latest subroutine.  No need for File::Find.  File::stat allows us to use names instead of trying to remember those numbers.  The program has a clearer structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;

my $watch_dir    = "C:\\eterra\\eterravision\\weather\\watch";
my $regional_dir = "C:\\eterra\\eterravision\\weather\\regional";

# get the latest in each directory
my $latest_regional = get_latest_file($regional_dir);
my $latest_watch    = get_latest_file($watch_dir);

# do whatever you want here...
process_latest ($latest_regional, $latest_watch);

# I exit 1 in Windows, exit 0 in Unix
exit 1;

#--------------------------------
# subroutines
#--------------------------------

sub get_latest_file {
    my $dir = shift;
    opendir my $DIR, $dir or die "$dir $!";
    my $latest_time = -1;
    my $latest_file = '';
    FILE:
    while (readdir($DIR)) {
        my $file = "$dir\\$_";
        next FILE unless -f $file;
        my $file_time = stat($file)->mtime;
        print "$file $file_time\n";
        if ($file_time > $latest_time) {
            $latest_time = $file_time;
            $latest_file = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir $DIR;
    return $latest_file;
}

sub process_latest {
    my $regional = shift;
    my $watch    = shift;

    print "Latest Regional: $regional\n";   
    print "Latest Watch:    $watch\n";

}
```